# Can't apply new normals to procedural mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

In Unity I'm creating a 3D procedural mesh using the Marching Cubes algorithm. My problem is that I'm trying to calculate the normals on my own to create a smooth shading effect. However, no matter what calculations I use nothing happens to the mesh, I am also not receiving any errors. I will leave you guys with some code and screenshots. If you need any more information or code please let me know. Thanks for your help!

My cave generation class:

```
// bool for autoUpdating the cave using the CaveGenerator
public bool autoUpdate;

// noise settings
[SerializeField] private int seed = 1;
[SerializeField] private float noiseScale = 1f;
[SerializeField] private float amplitude = 5f;
[SerializeField] private float frequency = 0.005f;
[SerializeField] private int octaves = 8;

// ground level
[SerializeField] private float isoLevel = 0.5f;

// mesh filter and shader
public MeshFilter MeshFilter;
public ComputeShader MarchingShader;

// buffers
private ComputeBuffer _trianglesBuffer;
private ComputeBuffer _trianglesCountBuffer;
private ComputeBuffer _weightsBuffer;

// triangle vertex data
struct Triangle {
    public Vector3 a;
    public Vector3 b;
    public Vector3 c;

    public static int SizeOf => sizeof(float) * 3 * 3;
}

// the noise generator and weights
public Noise Noise;
float[] _weights;

private void Awake() {
    CreateBuffers();
}

private void Start() {
    Generate();
}

private void OnDestroy() {
    ReleaseBuffers();
}

private void OnDrawGizmos() {
    // draw the cubes for gizmos
    if (_weights == null || _weights.Length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk; z++) {
                int index = x + GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * (y + GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * z);
                float noiseValue = _weights[index];
                Gizmos.color = Color.Lerp(Color.black, Color.white, noiseValue);
                Gizmos.DrawCube(new Vector3(x, y, z), Vector3.one * .2f);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Generate() {
    // get the weights and construct the mesh
    _weights = Noise.GetNoise(seed, noiseScale, amplitude, frequency, octaves);
    MeshFilter.sharedMesh = ConstructMesh();
}

void CreateBuffers() {
    // create buffers
    _trianglesBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(5 * (GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk), Triangle.SizeOf, ComputeBufferType.Append);
    _trianglesCountBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(1, sizeof(int), ComputeBufferType.Raw);
    _weightsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk * GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk, sizeof(float));
}

void ReleaseBuffers() {
    // destroy / release buffers
    _trianglesBuffer.Release();
    _trianglesCountBuffer.Release();
    _weightsBuffer.Release();
}

Mesh ConstructMesh() {
    // set the buffers
    MarchingShader.SetBuffer(0, "_Triangles", _trianglesBuffer);
    MarchingShader.SetBuffer(0, "_Weights", _weightsBuffer);

    // set the chunk settings
    MarchingShader.SetInt("_ChunkSize", GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk);
    MarchingShader.SetFloat("_IsoLevel", isoLevel);

    // set buffer data
    _trianglesBuffer.SetCounterValue(0);
    _weightsBuffer.SetData(_weights);

    // run the shader
    MarchingShader.Dispatch(0, GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk / GridMetrics.NumThreads, GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk / GridMetrics.NumThreads, GridMetrics.PointsPerChunk / GridMetrics.NumThreads);
    
    // get the triangles
    Triangle[] triangles = new Triangle[ReadTriangleCount()];
    _trianglesBuffer.GetData(triangles);

    // create a mesh from those triangles
    return CreateMeshFromTriangles(triangles);
}

Mesh CreateMeshFromTriangles(Triangle[] triangles) {
    // creat the mesh data arrays
    Vector3[] verts = new Vector3[triangles.Length * 3];
    int[] tris = new int[triangles.Length * 3];
    Vector3[] vertNormals = new Vector3[verts.Length];

    // set the verts and tris
    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++) {
        int startIndex = i * 3; 
        verts[startIndex] = triangles[i].a;
        verts[startIndex + 1] = triangles[i].b;
        verts[startIndex + 2] = triangles[i].c; 
        tris[startIndex] = startIndex;
        tris[startIndex + 1] = startIndex + 1;
        tris[startIndex + 2] = startIndex + 2;
    }

    // create the mesh and return it
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.vertices = verts;
    mesh.triangles = tris;
    mesh.normals = CalculateSmoothNormals(mesh.vertices, mesh.triangles, 60f);
    mesh.UploadMeshData(false);
    return mesh;
}

private Vector3[] CalculateSmoothNormals(Vector3[] vertices, int[] triangles, float smoothingAngle)
{
    Vector3[] smoothNormals = new Vector3[vertices.Length];

    // Calculate face normals
    Vector3[] faceNormals = new Vector3[triangles.Length / 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < faceNormals.Length; i++)
    {
        int i1 = triangles[i * 3];
        int i2 = triangles[i * 3 + 1];
        int i3 = triangles[i * 3 + 2];
        Vector3 v1 = vertices[i1];
        Vector3 v2 = vertices[i2];
        Vector3 v3 = vertices[i3];
        Vector3 side1 = v2 - v1;
        Vector3 side2 = v3 - v1;
        Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(side1, side2);
        faceNormals[i] = normal.normalized;
    }

    // Calculate smooth normals
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        List<int> sharedTriangles = new List<int>();
        for (int j = 0; j < triangles.Length; j++)
        {
            if (triangles[j] == i)
            {
                sharedTriangles.Add(j / 3);
            }
        }

        Vector3 smoothNormal = Vector3.zero;
        for (int j = 0; j < sharedTriangles.Count; j++)
        {
            int triangleIndex = sharedTriangles[j];
            Vector3 faceNormal = faceNormals[triangleIndex];
            if (Vector3.Angle(smoothNormal, faceNormal) < smoothingAngle)
            {
                smoothNormal += faceNormal;
            }
        }

        smoothNormals[i] = smoothNormal.normalized;
    }

    return smoothNormals;
}


int ReadTriangleCount() {
    // get the tri count
    int[] triCount = { 0 };
    ComputeBuffer.CopyCount(_trianglesBuffer, _trianglesCountBuffer, 0);
    _trianglesCountBuffer.GetData(triCount);
    return triCount[0];
}
```

My marching cubes compute shader:

```
#pragma kernel March

#include "Includes/MarchingTable.hlsl"
#include "Includes\MetricsCompute.compute"

// buffer
RWStructuredBuffer<float> _Weights;

// ground level
float _IsoLevel;

// triangle vertex data
struct Triangle {
    float3 a, b, c;
};

// buffer
AppendStructuredBuffer<Triangle> _Triangles;

// function to interpolate vertices' positions
float3 interp(float3 edgeVertex1, float valueAtVertex1, float3 edgeVertex2, float 
valueAtVertex2)
{
    return (edgeVertex1 + (_IsoLevel - valueAtVertex1) * (edgeVertex2 - edgeVertex1) / 
    (valueAtVertex2 - valueAtVertex1));
}

[numthreads(numThreads, numThreads, numThreads)]
void March(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{   
    // make sure we are in the chunk
    if (id.x >= _ChunkSize - 1 || id.y >= _ChunkSize - 1 || id.z >= _ChunkSize - 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    // get our cubes' noise values
    float cubeValues[8] = {
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x, id.y, id.z + 1)],
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x + 1, id.y, id.z + 1)],
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x + 1, id.y, id.z)],
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x, id.y, id.z)],
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x, id.y + 1, id.z + 1)],
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x + 1, id.y + 1, id.z + 1)],
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x + 1, id.y + 1, id.z)],
       _Weights[indexFromCoord(id.x, id.y + 1, id.z)]
    };

    // get the cubeIndex
    int cubeIndex = 0;
    if (cubeValues[0] < _IsoLevel) cubeIndex |= 1 << 0;
    if (cubeValues[1] < _IsoLevel) cubeIndex |= 1 << 1;
    if (cubeValues[2] < _IsoLevel) cubeIndex |= 1 << 2;
    if (cubeValues[3] < _IsoLevel) cubeIndex |= 1 << 3;
    if (cubeValues[5] < _IsoLevel) cubeIndex |= 1 << 5;
    if (cubeValues[6] < _IsoLevel) cubeIndex |= 1 << 6;
    if (cubeValues[7] < _IsoLevel) cubeIndex |= 1 << 7;

    // create array
    int edges[] = triTable[cubeIndex];

    // go through the edges and create the triangles
    for (int i = 0; edges[i] != -1; i += 3)
    {
        // First edge lies between vertex e00 and vertex e01
        int e00 = edgeConnections[edges[i]][0];
        int e01 = edgeConnections[edges[i]][1];

        // Second edge lies between vertex e10 and vertex e11
        int e10 = edgeConnections[edges[i + 1]][0];
        int e11 = edgeConnections[edges[i + 1]][1];
    
        // Third edge lies between vertex e20 and vertex e21
        int e20 = edgeConnections[edges[i + 2]][0];
        int e21 = edgeConnections[edges[i + 2]][1];

        Triangle tri;
        tri.a = interp(cornerOffsets[e00], cubeValues[e00], cornerOffsets[e01], cubeValues[e01]) + id;
        tri.b = interp(cornerOffsets[e10], cubeValues[e10], cornerOffsets[e11], cubeValues[e11]) + id;
        tri.c = interp(cornerOffsets[e20], cubeValues[e20], cornerOffsets[e21], cubeValues[e21]) + id;
        _Triangles.Append(tri);
    }
}
```

I am also using this custom editor script:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
    Cave cave = (Cave)target;

    if (DrawDefaultInspector()) {
        if (cave.autoUpdate) {
            cave.Generate();
        }
    }

    if (GUILayout.Button("Generate")) {
        cave.Generate();
    }
}
```

[image]